# Problema al validar un archivo XML con DTD

Tags: xml, validación

Al validar el documento con *DTD* me sale este error:

> XML document structures must start and end within the same entity

**XML:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Alumne SYSTEM "Activitat02.dtd>

<Alumne>
    <DadesPersonals>
        <Nom>Lavjit</Nom>
        <Cognom>Singh</Cognom>
        <Adreça>
            <Carrer>Frances Pla el Vigata</Carrer>
            <Numero>14</Numero>
            <Pis>1</Pis>
            <Porta>1</Porta>
            <Poblacio>Vic</Poblacio>
            <CP>08500</CP>
            <Provincia>Barcelona</Provincia>
        </Adreça>
    </DadesPersonals>
    <Ocupacio>Estudiant</Ocupacio>
    <Aficions>Videojocs, Llibres, Series, etc...</Aficions>
</Alumne>
```

**DTD:**

```xml
<!ELEMENT Alumne (DadesPersonals+,Ocupacio,Aficions)>

<!ELEMENT DadesPersonals (Nom,Cognom,Adreça+)>
<!ELEMENT Nom (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Cognom (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Adreça (Carrer,Numero,Pis,Porta,Poblacio,CP,Provincia)>
    <!ELEMENT Carrer (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT Numero (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT Pis (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT Porta (#PCDATA)>  
    <!ELEMENT Poblacio (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT CP (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT Provincia (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT Ocupacio (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Aficions (#PCDATA)>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probe tu ejemplo, los errores que vis fueron el la cabecera `<!DOCTYPE Alumne SYSTEM "Activitat02.dtd">` te faltaba un `"` al final.

```
<Alumne>
    <DadesPersonals>
        <Nom>Lavjit</Nom>
        <Cognom>Singh</Cognom>
        <Adreca>
            <Carrer>Frances Pla el Vigata</Carrer>
            <Numero>14</Numero>
            <Pis>1</Pis>
            <Porta>1</Porta>
            <Poblacio>Vic</Poblacio>
            <CP>08500</CP>
            <Provincia>Barcelona</Provincia>
        </Adreca>
    </DadesPersonals>
    <Ocupacio>Estudiant</Ocupacio>
    <Aficions>Videojocs, Llibres, Series, etc...</Aficions>
</Alumne>
```

Y en el archivo .dtd, cambie `Adreça` por `Adreca`, aunque talves sea un cambio que no influya en nada.

```
<!ELEMENT Alumne (DadesPersonals+,Ocupacio,Aficions)>
<!ELEMENT DadesPersonals (Nom,Cognom,Adreca+)>
<!ELEMENT Nom (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Cognom (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Adreça (Carrer,Numero,Pis,Porta,Poblacio,CP,Provincia)>
    <!ELEMENT Carrer (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT Numero (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT Pis (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT Porta (#PCDATA)>  
    <!ELEMENT Poblacio (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT CP (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT Provincia (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT Ocupacio (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Aficions (#PCDATA)>
```